# cypress e2e testing. Openlayers pan

Tags: triggers, cypress, openlayers, pan, e2e

I am trying, unsuccessfully, to pan the map triggering events like pointerdown, pointermove and pointerup using cypress.

This is the code I am using:

```
cy.get('.ol-viewport')
  .trigger('pointerdown', {
    clientX: 465,
    clientY: 412,
    force: true,
    eventConstructor: 'MouseEvent',        
    pointerId: 1        
  })
  .trigger('pointermove', {
    clientX: 325,
    clientY: 466,
    eventConstructor: 'MouseEvent',
    force: true,   
  })
cy.wait(1000)  

cy.get('.ol-viewport')
  .trigger('pointerup', {force: true})
```

Events are triggered. I know that because there is a DIV showing the mouse coordinates over the map. After triggering pointermouse event, the mouse coords are updated.

The problem is that pan never occurs.
Any thoughts?

I tried triggerging events with different params (poinerid, isPrimary, force) with no luck

Comment: This finally worked. First pointermove is ignored. No idea why.
cy.get('.ol-viewport')
      .trigger('pointerdown', {
        eventConstructor: 'MouseEvent',            
        x: 891, y: 544, force: true, isPrimary: true
      })
    cy.wait(1000)  
    cy.get('.ol-viewport')
      .trigger('pointermove', { x: 871, y: 530 })      
    cy.wait(1000)
    
    cy.get('.ol-viewport').trigger('pointermove', { x: 871, y: 500 })      
    cy.wait(1000)  
       
    cy.get('.ol-viewport').trigger('pointerup', {
        eventConstructor: 'MouseEvent',
        force: true
      })